# A list of arrays contained in a master array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I hope I can make this question clear enough.

I'm looking to put a list of arrays inside one master array, dynamically, so that it looks like this:

```
masterarray { 
array1 
{ [0]=>VAL1 [1]=>VAL2 } 
array2 
{ [0]=>VAL1 [1]=>VAL2 }
array3 
{ [0]=>VAL1 [1]=>VAL2 }
}
```

I've tried, but I could only get it to look like this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(13) "CODE" } } 
array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(13) "CODE" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(13) "CODE" } } 
array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(13) "CODE" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(13) "CODE" } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(13) "CODE" } }
```

And that's definitely not what I'm aiming for. Nothing seems contained. I need the format specified above.

I'm using the explode function on a string pulled from a file to make this table of arrays (I think you call it that)

Here is the code I'm using that's not working.

```
$variabledebugging = file("FILE.TXT");//LOOK IN THIS FILE FOR THE NUMBER AND SET IT TO A VAR.
$i=0;
foreach($variabledebugging as $placeholder){
$variabledebuggingtbl[] = explode("\t",$variabledebugging[$i]);
var_dump($variabledebuggingtbl);
$i++;
}
```

I've tried a couple of different variations, but that's the one I'm using now.

To be clear, that file being pulled (each line as a value in an array) has 2 things written to each line, separated by a tab character, so that's the system I'm going on.

Thank you! I'm sure this is a simple task, I just can't think it through.

Oh and while I'm at is there a way to make debugging more readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ARE getting the right result. The reason it seems wrong is that you are running var_dump inside the loop. And why don't you use the `$placeholder` variable?

```
$variabledebugging = file("FILE.TXT");
foreach($variabledebugging as $placeholder){
  $variabledebuggingtbl[] = explode("\t", $placeholder);
}
var_dump($variabledebuggingtbl);
```

---

I'm not sure what you mean by "making debugging more readable", but if you want some linebreaks and indentation you should just look in the generated HTML code. var_dump do add spacing to make it readable but it is ignored by the web browser. If you don't want to read the HTML source, just add your var_dump to a `<pre>` element.

Comment: Thank you! That works! I wasn't using $placeholder because it didn't seem to be working. Also is there a better way to read debugging?

Comment: Ok I'll try reading the source thanks. One more thing though. I can't seem to access the arrays. I get an error. Not sure if you get notified about these comments, being new to SO, but if you do can you tell me why I can't access them? I'm getting "Only variables can be passed by reference" and even if I weren't, to get the end array's first value would I do      end(array)[0]; or end(array[0]);?

Comment: $array[count($array)-1][0] or do it in two steps: $line = end($array); $line[0]. The "end($array)[0]" will be introduced to PHP shortly (or maybe it has been added in a very recent version, I'm so up-to-date on the topic).